# Create a random, sequenced id based on cookie session?

Tags: php, sql, cookies, registration

I have a user sign up or registration form to allow guests to my site become registered members. The form consists of first name, last name, email etc, the action goes to process_reg.php on submit.

The information is then inserted into an sql table 'ptb_registrations'. but it doesn't work yet because i am trying to randomly generate a new user id with the form from a cookie session. I'm not sure if what i'm doing is right. can people please correct me where I'm wrong or point me in the right direction. Thanks.

here's my script for process_reg.php:

```
<?php
require_once("session.php"); 
require_once("functions.php");
require('_config/connection.php');
?>
<?php 

session_start();

include '_config/connection.php'; 


function get_user_id() {
    global $connection;
    global $email;
    $query = "SELECT *
                FROM ptb_registrations
                WHERE email = \"$email\"
                ";
        $user_id_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
        confirm_query($user_id_set);
        return $user_id_set;
        }
?>
<?php
$user_id_set = get_user_id();
while ($user_id = mysql_fetch_array($user_id_set)) {
    $cookie1 = "{$user_id["id"]}";
    setcookie("ptb_registrations", $cookie1, time()+3600);  /* expire in 1 hour */

}
?>
<?

$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$display_name = $_POST['display_name'];
$date_of_birth = $_POST['date_of_birth'];
$contact_number = $_POST['contact_number'];
$station = $_POST['station'];
$hobbies = $_POST['hobbies'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$password = $_POST['password'];








$result = mysql_query("SELECT first_name FROM ptb_registrations WHERE id=".$cookie1['user_id']."");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT last_name FROM ptb_registrations WHERE id=".$cookie1['user_id']."");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT display_name FROM ptb_registrations WHERE id=".$cookie1['user_id']."");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM ptb_registrations WHERE id=".$cookie1['user_id']."");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT contact_number FROM ptb_registrations WHERE id=".$cookie1['user_id']."");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT date_of_birth FROM ptb_registrations WHERE id=".$cookie1['user_id']."");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT hobbies FROM ptb_registrations WHERE id=".$cookie1['user_id']."");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT station FROM ptb_registrations WHERE id=".$cookie1['user_id']."");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT gender FROM ptb_registrations WHERE id=".$cookie1['user_id']."");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT password FROM ptb_registrations WHERE id=".$cookie1['user_id']."");






if(!$result) 
{ 
echo "The username you entered does not exist"; 
} 
else 
if($email!= mysql_result($result, 0)) 
{ 
echo ""; 


    $sql=mysql_query("INSERT ptb_registrations SET first_name='$first_name' WHERE id=".$cookie1['user_id'].""); 
    $sql=mysql_query("INSERT ptb_registrations SET last_name='$last_name' WHERE id=".$cookie1['user_id'].""); 
    $sql=mysql_query("INSERT ptb_registrations SET display_name='$display_name' WHERE id=".$cookie1['user_id'].""); 
    $sql=mysql_query("INSERT ptb_registrations SET email='$email' WHERE id=".$cookie1['user_id'].""); 
    $sql=mysql_query("INSERT ptb_registrations SET contact_number='$contact_number' WHERE id=".$cookie1['user_id'].""); 
    $sql=mysql_query("INSERT ptb_registrations SET date_of_birth='$date_of_birth' WHERE id=".$cookie1['user_id'].""); 
    $sql=mysql_query("INSERT ptb_registrations SET hobbies='$hobbies' WHERE id=".$cookie1['user_id'].""); 
    $sql=mysql_query("INSERT ptb_registrations SET station='$station' WHERE id=".$cookie1['user_id'].""); 
    $sql=mysql_query("INSERT ptb_registrations SET gender='$gender' WHERE id=".$cookie1['user_id'].""); 
    $sql=mysql_query("INSERT ptb_registrations SET password='$password' WHERE id=".$cookie1['user_id'].""); 


}
    if($sql) 
    { 
    echo "<div class=\"infobox-profile\"> <strong>Thank You</strong> - We have received your registration details.</div>"; 
    }
else
{ 
echo "<div class=\"infobox-profile\"> <strong>Oooops!</strong> - Something went wrong. <a href=\"../edit_contact_number.php\">Click here</a> to try again.</div>"; 
}  
?>
<? ob_flush(); ?>

<style>
.infobox-profile {
    background-color: #e1e0f7;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #181469;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-image: url(../img/icons/info-icon.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 15px center;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #8f8fdb;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-right-color: #8f8fdb;
    border-bottom-color: #8f8fdb;
    border-left-color: #8f8fdb;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 385px;
    margin-left:8px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Why do you care if the user id is random?

Comment: Why do you generate it and not use autoincrement column?

Comment: well i just want any user id to be produced but i don't want the same id twice. so would need to be sequenced. and i am new to php and sql and i'm not sure what you mean by auto increment?

Comment: Your 10 back-to-back MySQL SELECT queries are extremely ... odd

Comment: Also what happens if user provides `$email` as `"; SHOW TABLES;`

Answer (score 1):

A random generated number is not always completely random and after a while you will always get the same number again. This is because these numbers are generated by a PSEUDOrandom number generator. Because you work with a mysql database the best solution for your problem is to use the auto increment attribute. Every time a new user is added to the database  this field will be increased by one.

Here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE animals (
     id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```